# Why do I keep getting this ? The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file

Tags: http-status-code-404

404 error:
[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help me? I've watched 2 days worth of videos, and I still can't seem to figure this out. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried renaming `Index.html` to `index.html` to match the filename in the error message? Some web servers are case-sensitive

Comment: Yeah I got some help yesterday and that indeed was the issue with fixing the error. Thanks @RemyLebeau